# Getting 'NoClassDefFoundError' (com/../JsonSchemaFactory) when trying to validate schema in Rest-Assured tool

Tags: rest-assured, json-schema-validator, web-api-testing

We are trying to validate a JSON response to see if it matches a schema placed in the Eclipse ClassPath. This is designed to be a Maven project and I believe we have all the dependencies in place. But we are always getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/fge/jsonschema/main/JsonSchemaFactory
    at com.jayway.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidatorSettings.<init>(JsonSchemaValidatorSettings.java:58)
    at com.jayway.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator$JsonSchemaValidatorFactory.createSettings(JsonSchemaValidator.java:277)
    at com.jayway.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator$JsonSchemaValidatorFactory.create(JsonSchemaValidator.java:289)
    at com.jayway.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchema(JsonSchemaValidator.java:166)
    at com.jayway.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath(JsonSchemaValidator.java:117)
    at com.macys.xapi.ProductServices.TestProductServices.ohGodImDoomed(TestProductServices.java:76)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
```

We have the following dependencies in place:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-coreutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Not sure what we are missing here - can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vishnu, Just add following dependencies and remove all above dependencies.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>


 <dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, Ramu! It worked when I built my .m2 repository again. Seems to me there was a conflict with the latest Rest-Assured version (3.x) versus the old versions (2.x) - since we were experimenting with both, we caught this problem.